# alternate proof for $\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform

There are many proofs out there for $\sum_{n\in N} n^{-2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$. I am looking for a proof/reference of the following way that uses convergence Fourier series. First using the Poisson kernel on $R$, given by $k(x)=\frac{1}{\pi(1+x^2)}$ we get derive an identity
$$\sum_{n\in Z}(n^2+t^2)^{-1}=\frac{\pi}{t}\frac{1+e^{-2\pi t}}{1-e^{-2\pi t}}$$
and then taking limits of the above as $t\to 0$ we deduce the result. However I dont understand where this identity comes from and the limit part, what technique is used.

Comment: Any post of this sort needs a link to Robin Chapman's gallery of ways of evaluating $\zeta(2)$.  https://empslocal.ex.ac.uk/people/staff/rjchapma/etc/zeta2.pdf

Comment: was the first I checked before posting my problem :). it wasn't there but the problem posted above is found in a few Fourier textbooks without proof.

Comment: @leslietownes Just for information: Robin Chapman is deceased last year.

Comment: Robin was a valued contributor here, https://math.stackexchange.com/users/226/robin-chapman and also on MathOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Let $f\in\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$. Then
> $$\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}f(n) = \sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}\hat f(k),$$
> where $\hat f$ is the Fourier transformation of $f$.

By Cauchy’s integral formula,
$$\mathcal{F}\left\{(n^2+t^2)^{-1}\right\}(\omega)=\int_\mathbb{R}\frac{1}{x^2+t^2}e^{-2\pi i\omega x}\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac{\pi}{t}e^{-2\pi tt\lvert \omega\rvert}$$
By the Poisson summation formula, we obtain
$$\sum_{n\in \mathbb{Z}}(n^2+t^2)^{-1}=\sum_{n\in \mathbb{Z}}\frac{\pi}{t}e^{-2\pi tt\lvert \omega\rvert}=\frac{\pi }{t}\frac{1+e^{2\pi t}}{1-e^{2\pi t}}$$

As $t\to0$ note that the sum diverges, since it goes over $\frac{1}{0^2}$.

*Reference: https://blog.zilin.one/2014/12/05/poisson-summation-formula-and-basel-problem/*

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to establish the equality:

$$
\sum_{n\in \mathbb Z}\frac1{n^2+t^2}=\frac{\pi\coth\pi t}t\tag1
$$
is to apply [Mittag-Leffler's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mittag-Leffler%27s_theorem).

From $(1)$ we derive:
$$
2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^2+t^2}=\frac{\pi\coth\pi t}t-\frac1{t^2}\tag2
$$
which in the limit $t\to0$ gives:
$$
2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^2}=\lim_{t\to 0}\left[\frac{\pi\coth\pi t}t-\frac1{t^2}\right]=\frac{\pi^2}3\tag3
$$
where we used the well-known [Laurent series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_functions#Taylor_series_expressions):
$$
\coth x=\frac1x+\frac x3-\mathcal O(x^3)
$$